# javascript and jQuery hide method not working while data loaded through ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

this is my ajax code

```
var ajaxRequest;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObect('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
}

ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if ( ajaxRequest.readyState==4 && ajaxRequest.status==200 ) { 
                    alert('data loaded');
                    var loadedData = document.getElementById('page-data');
                    loadedData.innerHTML=ajaxRequest.responseText; 
                }
            }

// load data from server
function getData() {
    ajaxRequest.open('POST', 'loadData.php', true);
    ajaxRequest.send();
}
```

`alert()` function is not working but `getElementById()` function is working properly
can anyone tell me that why `alert()` function is not working? and if I write another statement in place of `alert()` function it is also not working but next line is working

Comment: I bet you push button on optional checkbox -  "don't show alerts from this site" and close alert.

Comment: If I'm wrong, search somewhere in your code - `function alert(){}`

Comment: what relevance is jQuery to this? There's no jQuery in your code or your question, yet it's tagged and is in the question title. Don't include irrelevant information please.

Comment: Including jQuery means I have tried both js and jQuery.